# How to Compile Games within my Game Engine in C++

Tags: c++, compilation, architecture, game-engine

I am working on a game engine in C++, using Visual Studio.

In game engines such as Unity, the game can be played through the engine, but then can be compiled through the engine into an executable file (such as `.exe`, `.apk`, etc.).

I want to implement a system like this, however I am stuck on how game engines are able to compile games within the engine. Since the actual engine will have been compiled for a specific platform (such as Windows, for example), the engine must include its own compiler to be able to build games for other platforms (Linux, Android, etc).

What I am wondering is, how would I go about implementing a system like this in my own game engine, where I can compile the engine, and then within the engine I would be able to compile games?

Comment: The engine will provide a scripting language. This language will be interpreted. Likely the executable file will simply be the script file bundled with the interpreter and configured to automatically load and run the script.

Answer (score 1):

You would not have to have the end user compile your engine for each target. You would have to have them [cross-compile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler) their game code and link pre-supplied engine libraries into an executable for each target.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I'm still a little bit confused. If you have a game engine which is supplied to the end user with an interface, level editor etc., this would be supplied as an executable. But then when the user wants to build their game, the engine would link as a library and would have lots of the functionality removed. Am I right in what I am thinking? And how would you implement something like this?

Comment: You don't even try to compile the user's game. You bundle up all of the game's resources, the script that describes the game and the game engine's pre-compiled script interpreter for the target platform into a nice executable bundle. The executable then runs the script through the interpreter and the script does its thing.

Comment: The "game engine" is probably a library for your development host. The IDE, editor, etc. are probably application written to use your game engine library and probably some other libraries. When you compile and link your game into a standalone executable, it will link in the appropriate libraries from the game engine for the target.

At least, that's how popular game engines like Unreal, Unity, Source, and Godot work. Other engine work more like Java, JavaScript, or Python where you just have a scripting language interpreted by a separate application you need to bundle.